# Why Am I Getting This Error? 405 Not Allowed In Html

Tags: html, coldfusion, http-status-code-405

I found this code used to post comments on a webpage:

```
<form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="post">
    <div>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" style="font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;">
            Hey... say something!
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
```

Whenever I submit something, I get an error that says:

> 405 Not Allowed
>
> nginx

Any help on as what to do?

Comment: Are you not actually running any ColdFusion and are just expecting to put this in a document and have it produce comments? That’s not how it works. The form will send a request with the comment body, but you have to process it yourself on the server.

Answer (score 4):

`405` errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the `POST` method necessary to process the form.

All `405` errors can be traced to configuration of the Web server and security governing access to the content of the Web site, so should easily be explained by your ISP.

Find details [here](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html)